# Returning greater than and less than values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to return values less than 40 and greater than 100 in a column using pandas. The current line of code that I am using only returns the values between 40 and 100 (so basically the opposite range that I want).

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Test = df[(df['QC 1'] >= 40) & (df['QC 1'] <= 100)]

print(Test)
```

I feel like I'm probably missing something very obvious here but I haven't been able to figure out what that is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `>=` to `<`, `<=` to `>` and `|` for bitwise `OR`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'QC 1':[10,50,300],'B':[8,2,0]})

test = df[(df['QC 1'] < 40) | (df['QC 1'] > 100)]
print(test)
   QC 1  B
0    10  8
2   300  0
```

Working same like inverted mask in your solution:

```
Test = df[~((df['QC 1'] >= 40) & (df['QC 1'] <= 100))]
```